# Extract transactionId from app store in-app purchase receipt without using App Store Server Library

Tags: .net, in-app-purchase, app-store, deprecated

Because the endpoint **/verifyReceipt** is deprecated. I am migrating my server following the instruction of Apple for validating in-app purchase transaction.

Here's the changed flow

Old
[image]

New
[image]

The new flow requires using [App Store Server Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/simplifying_your_implementation_by_using_the_app_store_server_library)

The problem is this library only supports 4 languages (Java, Swift, Python, Node) yet my server is running on .Net. then I can not use the method `ReceiptUtility::getTransactionIdFromAppReceipt`

Anybody can drop me some docs that refer to the alternative api url that responding to the method `ReceiptUtility::getTransactionIdFromAppReceipt`

Any answer is so appreciated.

**----- Edited: Issue resolved ------**

I found out an library which can replace the AppStore-provided one
https://github.com/shoshins/apple-receipt

This library provide us 2 main functions: validator the receipt and parse the receipt. However, the validator is based on the obsolete url (`/verifyReceipt`). Then the better approach is to parse the receipt to get the `originalTransactionId` then using `App Store Server API` to call the endpoint `/inApps/v1/history/{originalTransactionId}` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history)

Also, another repo you can refer to know how to use the `App Store Server API`
https://github.com/dragouf/AppStoreServerApi/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using Microservices for Appstore Server API for case you have used .Net before, more specific:

- Create project just only handle flow payment with appstore notification v2 (Decode signedPayload from appstore)
- After decode you have a data, from here you can call the API that you have defined in your .Net backend, along with the body that you decoded in the step above
- Final processing save to my database with logic of you

Comment: alright thanks, I have added my resolution to my post in case if someone need it